# MySQL Logic issue using 'Between' to calculate coordinates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains a list of stores, with Latitude and Longitude.
I doing the following query:

```
SELECT store_name, latitude FROM (`stores`)
WHERE (latitude BETWEEN '-1' AND '-12')

The Result:
"BELEM UMARIZAL"            "-1.4454262"
"BELEM NAZARE DUQUE"        "-1.454061"
"BELEM SUPERCENTER NAZARE"  "-1.4595652"
"BELEM BATISTA CAMPOS"      "-1.459802"
"ARACAJU"                   "-10.9336128"
"BELEM DOMINGOS MARREIROS"  "-1.4443628"
"PALMAS "                   "-10.178152"
"SINOP"                     "-11.8573162"
"ARACAJU JARDINS"           "-10.942702"

SELECT store_name, latitude FROM (`stores`)
WHERE store_name like '%RIO BRANCO%'

The Result:
"RIO BRANCO"            "-9.9462713"
"RIO BRANCO AVIÁRIO"    "-9.965754700000002"
```

Why these stores are not in the first result?
What I am missing?

Best Regards!

Comment: What column type is latitude? It looks like a string. It should be a float if you want to run numeric comparisons on it. Also try `BETWEEN -12 AND -1` instead.

Comment: Remember number lines from school? -12 is less than -1.

Comment: [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you are storing the values as *strings* not as numbers.  Hence, the comparisons are done as strings.  One way to fix this is to use silent conversion:

```
SELECT store_name, latitude
FROM stores
WHERE latitude + 0 BETWEEN -12 AND -1;
```

However, if you want to treat the values as numbers, you should store them as numbers.  I would recommend `DECIMAL(10, 6)`.

Note:

As originally written, the expression:

```
WHERE latitude + 0 BETWEEN -1 AND -12
```

would return no rows, because -1 is larger than -12 and the operands to `BETWEEN` should be in order.  However, do note that it does work with strings . . . further indicating the difference between string and numeric comparisons.